# Multiple Publications for Merge Replication?

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am designing a system which will have one SQL server 2012 central database.

Each client will user merge replication to take an offline copy of their data to edit on the road.

If I add a publication I can add filters to that publication. The thing I can't work out though is that is only one set of filters.

For each client I have they will have a different set of filters to filter data that relates to them only. This is quite important from a security point of view.

How is this achieved with only one publication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done in Merge Replication by using [Parameterized Row Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152478.aspx).  They allow for different partitions of data to go to different Subscribers without requiring multiple publications.